# Javascript button not working properly with bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, forms, bootstrap-4

I am creating dynamic divs on a modal form with a close button destroying them and so far works fine.
Then, I added a button to add new divs/forms items, but this time the close button callback is not called and close the modal rather than destroy the div itself. The callback function is not called when the rows are created from *addNewRow*. Here is the code:

```js
console.log("hello");

var myModal = $('#exampleModal'); 

var myForm = $('#exampleModal #myForm'); 
var value = $('#redactorArea3').val(); 
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(value); 

var recordsCounter = 0;

for (var index in result){

  var obj = result[index];
  var mydiv = '<div id="pepe'+index+'" class="input-group mb-3">';
  for (var property in obj){
    var attrName = property;
    var attrValue = obj[property]; 

   
   //myForm.append('<div class="form-group"><label>'+attrName+'</label><textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="1">'+ attrValue +'</textarea></div>');
   
    mydiv += '<div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">'+attrName+'</span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field'+index+'"  value="'+attrValue+'">';

  }  
  mydiv += '<button id="remove' + index + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >-</button></div>';
  myForm.append( mydiv);
  recordsCounter++;
}    
            
function addNewRow(){
    recordsCounter++;
    var mydiv = '<div id="pepe'+recordsCounter+'" class="input-group mb-3">';
    mydiv += '<div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"></span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field'+recordsCounter+'">';
    mydiv += '<div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"></span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field'+recordsCounter+'">';
    mydiv += '<button id="remove' + recordsCounter + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >-</button></div>';
    myForm.append( mydiv);
  console.log("add row");
}

$('.remove-me').click(function(e){
                console.log("remove me");
                e.preventDefault();
                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
                var pepeId = "#pepe" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();
                $(pepeId).remove();
                recordsCounter--;
            });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Mara test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Show modal
  </button>

  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Database management</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="data_list">
          <ul>
          </ul>
          <form id="myForm">
            <div id="formItems">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addNewRow();">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="d-none">
   
    <textarea id="redactorArea3" class="text-justify">[{"name": "S","price": "20.00"},{"name":"M","price": "20.00"},{"name":"L","price": "20.00"},{"name":"XL","price": "20.00"},{"name":"2XL","price": "21.00"},{"name":"3XL","price": "22.00"}]</textarea>
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="mara.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you defining the events which are not being called?  most likely it's because the rows are added after the events are added.  for dynamically created elements, you need to delegate events a parent element with .on().

Comment: also, a suggestion: if you create a (non) working code sample in your question, it will make it a *lot* easier for people to help you.  in your code sample above, a lot of important details are left out such as how you are setting up event handlers, the HTML, etc.

Comment: thx, I just added the full code. The vents are  linked to bootstraps classes

Comment: ok, so notice this code here: `$('.remove-me').click(...)` you are attaching events to all elements returned from the selector `$('.remove-me')`, but this will never include dynamic elements which don't exist yet at the time that line of code runs.  in order to bind to future elements, you need to _delegate_ the event handler to a parent or higher element.  In this case, you could try `$('.input-group.mb-3).on('click', '.remove-me, function(e) {...})`

Comment: Please read https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my selector above wasn't quite right but here is a working version.  Also, by the way your `addNewRow()` method doesn't add the *Name* and *Price* labels.

```js
console.log("hello");

var myModal = $('#exampleModal'); 

var myForm = $('#exampleModal #myForm'); 
var value = $('#redactorArea3').val(); 
var result = jQuery.parseJSON(value); 

var recordsCounter = 0;

for (var index in result){

  var obj = result[index];
  var mydiv = '<div id="pepe'+index+'" class="input-group mb-3">';
  for (var property in obj){
    var attrName = property;
    var attrValue = obj[property]; 

   
   //myForm.append('<div class="form-group"><label>'+attrName+'</label><textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="1">'+ attrValue +'</textarea></div>');
   
    mydiv += '<div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">'+attrName+'</span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field'+index+'"  value="'+attrValue+'">';

  }  
  mydiv += '<button id="remove' + index + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >-</button></div>';
  myForm.append( mydiv);
  recordsCounter++;
}    
            
function addNewRow(){
    recordsCounter++;
    var mydiv = '<div id="pepe'+recordsCounter+'" class="input-group mb-3">';
    mydiv += '<div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"></span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field'+recordsCounter+'">';
    mydiv += '<div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text"></span></div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field'+recordsCounter+'">';
    mydiv += '<button id="remove' + recordsCounter + '" class="btn btn-danger remove-me" >-</button></div>';
    myForm.append( mydiv);
  console.log("add row");
}

$('#myForm').on('click', '.remove-me', function(e){
debugger;
                console.log("remove me");
                e.preventDefault();
                var fieldNum = this.id.charAt(this.id.length-1);
                var fieldID = "#field" + fieldNum;
                var pepeId = "#pepe" + fieldNum;
                $(this).remove();
                $(fieldID).remove();
                $(pepeId).remove();
                recordsCounter--;
            });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Mara test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
    Show modal
  </button>

  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Database management</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="data_list">
          <ul>
          </ul>
          <form id="myForm">
            <div id="formItems">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addNewRow();">+</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="d-none">
   
    <textarea id="redactorArea3" class="text-justify">[{"name": "S","price": "20.00"},{"name":"M","price": "20.00"},{"name":"L","price": "20.00"},{"name":"XL","price": "20.00"},{"name":"2XL","price": "21.00"},{"name":"3XL","price": "22.00"}]</textarea>
  </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="mara.js"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```